# Rails - 500 from Server on JQuery Ajax POST (also on GET)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, post

Ok, my brain is fried from looking at this! Can anyone see what's wrong?
One possibility is that the @profile object is not being populated on load of the partial, though I shouldn't actually need to render the partial on the html.erb page if the Ajax was working properly!

Here we go:

html.erb:

```
<div id="stars">
<%= render :partial => 'stars' %>
</div>
```

stars partial:

```
<p>
  <b><strong>Stars! </strong></b>
    <%= @profile.stars %>
    <input type="submit" name="one" id="one" value="+1" message="<%= @profile.id %>">
</p>
```

javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $("#one").click(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/rate",
    dataType: "html",
    data: "prof="+this.getAttribute("message"),
    success: function(data){
        $("#stars").html(data);
        }
    });
  })
});
```

and controller:

```
  def rate
@rate_this_profile = Profile.find_by_id(params[:prof])
if @rate_this_profile
  @rate_this_profile.stars += 1

  respond_to do |format|           --Line 177
  if @rate_this_profile.save

    render :partial => "stars"     --Line 180

    flash[:success] = "Rated!"
  else
    flash[:success] = "Failed"
  end
end
end
```

end

Logs:

```
Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-12-18 22:01:51 +0000
Served asset /application.js - 304 Not Modified (3ms)


Started POST "/rate" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-12-18 22:13:23 +0000
  Processing by ProfilesController#rate as HTML
   Parameters: {"prof"=>"3"}
   ←[1m←[35mProfile Load (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE  "profiles"."id" = 3 LIMIT 1
  ←[1m←[36m (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mUPDATE "profiles" SET "stars" = 21, "updated_at" = '2011-12-18 22:13:23.493276' WHERE "profiles"."id" = 3←[0m
Rendered profiles/_stars.html.erb (7.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 93ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `stars' for nil:NilClass):
1: <p>

2:   <b><strong>Stars! </strong></b>

3:          <%= @profile.stars %>

4:          <input type="submit" name="one" id="one" value="+1" message="<%= @profile.id %>">

5: </p>
  app/views/profiles/_stars.html.erb:3:in      `_app_views_profiles__stars_html_erb__1034491404_54471564'
  app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb:180:in `block in rate'
  app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb:177:in `rate'

Rendered c:/Ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered c:/Ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered c:/Ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (37.0ms)
```

Comment: You define `@rate_this_profile` but not `@profile` so `@profile` is auto-created on first use and starts as `nil`. So there's your bug and I'm voting to close as "too localized".

Comment: @muistooshort I have only shown a part of the files. The parts I thought relevant. If you would like to see more, please ask. The profile is not nil for the rest of the html. It is only in the partial that it is nil.

Comment: @spuriosity You should show the part where you initialize `@profile`, because the Ajax post method doesn't, and that's what's being run before the render of the partial. Where `@profile` is `nil`. What makes you think when you make a new request that the *previous@ request's `@profile` will still be valid?

Comment: Why would you expect `@profile` to be defined when `rate` is called?

Comment: Can you try changing the line that reads `@profile.stars` to `@profile.try(:stars)` and see if it still prints out an error.

Comment: Any reason not to handle the responses via a .js.erb in case of format.js?  I am a newbie, so please ignore the comment if it does not help.  I just thought of mentioning because I got my ajax thing working after 2 days of headache.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller is rendering he partial stars, regardless of the format. If you setup @profile in the rate method, does it fix it?

Another, perhaps more elegant, option is to change your render to this:

```
render :partial => 'stars', :locals => { :profile => whatever_you_want_here }
```

And change your partial to use "profile" instead of "@profile"